# Is there any asp.net ef core method to get foreign table data without same datatype

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-core

Actually I am switching from laravel mvc to asp.net blazor. I am quite happy with all the features of asp.net and models from scaffolding database. Now the issues is that i have two tables with different datatype like designationcode is string on employees table and designationcode is int of it's own table as PK

Now in Laravel we have a way to map these things but c# is strongly typed is there any way to somehow declare this as foreign key in model and then get designation as a property of employee model. Sorry for bit confusing actually I am comparing to eloquent in Laravel and somehow trying to achieve this without writing raw query.

tblEmployee is

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

#nullable disable

namespace Bzu_Employees_Management.Models
{
    public partial class TblEmployee
    {
        public TblEmployee()
        {
            Employeefrcs = new HashSet<Employeefrc>();
            TblEmployeeDesignations = new HashSet<TblEmployeeDesignation>();
        }

        public string EmployeeCode { get; set; }
        public string DepartmentCode { get; set; }
        public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
        public string FatherName { get; set; }
        public string CellNo { get; set; }
        public string CnicNo { get; set; }
        public string JobStatus { get; set; }
        public string DesignationCode
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public string OldDob { get; set; }
        public string OldDor { get; set; }
        public string OldDoj { get; set; }
        public string VisitingDesignation { get; set; }
        public string VisitingDepartments { get; set; }
        public string OfficeAddress { get; set; }
        public string PermanentAddress { get; set; }
        public string CurrentAddress { get; set; }
        public string OfficialEmail { get; set; }
        public string PersonalEmail { get; set; }
        public string Nationality { get; set; }
        public string DomicileDistrict { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public string NtnNumber { get; set; }
        public int? Bps { get; set; }
        public string EmployeeImage { get; set; }
        public string OldEmployeeCode { get; set; }
        public string EmployeeStatus { get; set; }
        public string Remarks { get; set; }
        public DateTime? CreatedAt { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DateOfJoining { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DateOfRetirement { get; set; }

        public virtual TblDepartment DepartmentCodeNavigation { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Employeefrc> Employeefrcs { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<TblEmployeeDesignation> TblEmployeeDesignations { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and my other table is tblDepartment is

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

#nullable disable

namespace Bzu_Employees_Management.Models
{
    public partial class TblEmployeeDesignation
    {
        public int EmployeeDesignationId { get; set; }
        public int DesignationId { get; set; }
        public string EmployeeCode { get; set; }
        public int? DesignationDesignationCode { get; set; }

        public virtual TblDesignation DesignationDesignationCodeNavigation { get; set; }
        public virtual TblEmployee EmployeeCodeNavigation { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not fix your DB schema so that it's consistent? Make `designationcode` an int on the employees table. Then you won't have to resort to weird workarounds, and you can set up a proper foreign key reference.

Comment: Actually db is in production and i can't risk any data as well as it's timing out in testing as well for conversion. In laravel it's possible so somehow i thought there might be someway to link these tables without physical foreign key relationship

Comment: It's in production? All the more reason to get it fixed properly ASAP. If it's timing out when you try to fix it...update your timeout or update it in smaller batches.

Comment: @mason so there's not any other possible solution ?

Comment: I'm sure you could cobble something together. But ultimately it's going to be far more trouble than just fixing your database.

Comment: @mason Now i have fixed my database and posted another question i have annotated a property in tblEmployee class with foregin key as i did same FK relationship in database as well but still that is retuning null. I know there is workaround by using joins but i never used in laravel ORM so i thought that will be same here in EF as well. Any help will be appreciated.